# Show/hide DIV with create, edit, delete

Tags: php, jquery, crud

I have three buttons (create,edit,delete) with three separate functions defined in a class.

When I click on create, create function should be called and likewise for edit and delete.

Everything was working fine up-to here, but when I click on submit in anyone of the options(create/edit/delete), the page is redirecting by displaying the first div "cs_content" all the time.

My Requirement is : Until the data is stored to database successfully by submitting, then only the page should redirect to "cs_content" else in case any errors, the page should be 
on the selected div.

```
 $ (document).ready(function () 
    {
      //$("#cs_content").show();
      $('#cs').click(function () 
      {
            $('#cs_content').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#rp_content').hide();
      });
      $('#ed').click(function () 
      {
            $('#ed_content').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#cs_content').hide();
      });

      $('#del').click(function () 
      {
            $('#del_content').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#ed_content').hide();
      });
    });



            <div class="container2">        
              <div id="cs" style="float:left;margin:0px 0px;padding:7px;"><input type="button" value="Create"></div>
              <div id="ed" style="float:left;margin:0px 0px;padding:7px;"><input type="button" value="Edit"></div>
              <div id="del" style="float:left;margin:0px 0px;padding:7px;"><input type="button" value="Delete"></div>

               <div id="cs_content"><?php $ds->create_ds($db_host,$db_username,$db_password); ?> </div>        
               <div id="ed_content" style="display:none;"> <?php $ds->update_ds($db_host,$db_username,$db_password); ?>  </div>
               <div id="del_content" style="display:none;"> <?php $ds->delete_ds($db_host,$db_username,$db_password); ?>  </div>
            </div>
```

Updated code:

```
class Datasource 
 {
       private $db;

       public function __construct($database){
          $this->db = $database;
       }

       //CREATE DATASOURCE
       public function create_ds($db_host,$db_username,$db_password)
       {
           if (isset($_POST['create_dsource']))
           {      
              $dsource_host = htmlentities($_POST['dsource_host']); 
              $dsource_username = htmlentities($_POST['dsource_username']); 
              $dsource_password = $_POST['dsource_password']; 
              $dsource_name = htmlentities($_POST['dsource_name']); 

              if (empty($_POST['dsource_host']) || empty($_POST['dsource_username']) || empty($_POST['dsource_name']))
              {
                 $errors[] = '<span class="error">All fields are required.</span>';
              }
              else
              {
                 if (isset($_POST['dsource_host']) && empty($_POST['dsource_host'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Datasource Host is required</span>'; }
                 else if ($_POST['dsource_host'] !== $db_host)
                 {  $errors[] = '<span class="error">dsource Host is not matching with the application data source host </span>';  }


                 if(isset($_POST['dsource_username']) && empty($_POST['dsource_username'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Datasource username is required</span>';  }
                 else if ($_POST['dsource_username'] !== $db_username)
                 {  $errors[] = '<span class="error">Datasource Username is not matching with the application datasource username </span>';  }


                 if ($_POST['dsource_password'] !== $db_password)
                 {  $errors[] = '<span class="error">Datasource Password is not matching with the application datasource password </span>';  }


                 if (isset($_POST['dsource_name']) && empty($_POST['dsource_name'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Datasource name is required</span>'; }
                 else if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['dsource_name']))
                 {  $errors[] = '<span class="error">Please enter a datasource name with only alphabets and numbers</span>';  }
              }     

              if (empty($errors) === true)
              {                    
                 try 
                 {   
                    $this->db->exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ".$dsource_name."");
                    $this->db->query("USE ".$dsource_name."");

                    $sql_filename = "includes/datasource.sql";
                    $sql_contents = file_get_contents($sql_filename);
                    $sql_contents = explode("@@", $sql_contents);           

                    foreach($sql_contents as $query)
                    {
                       $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
                       $result->execute();        
                    }
                 }  
                 catch (PDOException $e) {
                     die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
                 }                  
                 header('Location:home.php?success');
                 exit();
              }
           }    

           if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) 
           { 
              header('Refresh:0; url=home.php');
              echo '<span class="error">Datasource is succesfully created</span>';  
           }

           ?>
           <form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="create_ds" name="create_ds">
             <table class="create_dsource">
               <tr><td><label>Datasource Host</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="dsource_host" required placeholder="localhost/server" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["dsource_host"])) echo $dsource_host; ?>" size="30">            
               </td></tr>

               <tr><td><label>Datasource Username</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="dsource_username" required placeholder="Datasource username" size="30" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["dsource_username"])) echo $dsource_username; ?>">                                 
               </td></tr>

               <tr><td><label>Datasource Password</label></td>
                   <td><input type="password" name="dsource_password" placeholder="Datasource password" size="30" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["dsource_password"])) echo $dsource_password; ?>" autocomplete="off">                                    
               </td></tr>

               <tr><td><label>Datasource Name</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
                   <td><input type="text" name="dsource_name" size="30" required placeholder="Datasource name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["dsource_name"])) echo $dsource_name; ?>">                                  
               </td></tr>

               <tr><td><input type="submit" value="create datasource" style="background:#8AC007;color:#080808;padding:6px;" name="create_dsource"></td></tr> 
             </table>
           </form>

           <?php             
             //IF THERE ARE ERRORS, THEY WOULD BE DISPLAY HERE
             if (empty($errors) === false) 
             echo '<div>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</div>';             
       }
} //class closes here

$ds = new Datasource($db);
```

Comment: I think you are looking for jquery ajax function where you can call database to save data and it return success or fail. you read the status success or fail and redirect accordingly. see for more info http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED WITH EXAMPLE.**

You doing bad mistake it's not the right way to do what you want.

You should use ajax.

Read here [jQuery.AJAX guide](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) .

I made you example how to do it VERY BASIC but will do the job:

HTML PAGE :

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

   $ (document).ready(function () 
    {
      //$("#cs_content").show();
      $('#cs').click(function () 
      {
         createDs();
      });
      $('#ed').click(function () 
      {
          updateDs();
      });

      $('#del').click(function () 
      {
          deleteDs();
      });
    });


function createDs(){

     $.ajax({  
      url: "check.php?proc=create",
      type: "POST",  
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(data)
      {  
             $('#returnMessage').show();
             $('#returnMessage').html(data.mes);
      }


   });  

return false;
}

function updateDs(){
    
     $.ajax({  
      url: "check.php?proc=update",
      type: "POST",  
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(data)
      {  
          $('#returnMessage').show();
          $('#returnMessage').html(data.mes);
      }


   });  

return false;
}

function deleteDs(){


     $.ajax({  
      url: "check.php?proc=delete",
      type: "POST",  
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(data)
      {  
       $('#returnMessage').show();
        $('#returnMessage').html(data.mes);
      }

   });  

return false;
}

  </script>

<div class="container2">        
      <div style="float:left;margin:0px 0px;padding:7px;"><input type="submit" value="Create" id="cs"></div>
      <div  style="float:left;margin:0px 0px;padding:7px;"><input type="submit" value="Edit" id="ed"></div>
      <div  style="float:left;margin:0px 0px;padding:7px;"><input type="submit" value="Delete" id="del"></div>
       <div  style="float:left;margin:0px 0px;padding:7px;"><input type="submit" value="Clear DIV" id="clear"></div>

       <div id="returnMessage" style="display:none;"></div>        

           <div id="returnMessage" style="display:none;"></div>        

        </div>
```

check.php: (don't forget include here $ds-)

```
 <?php

    //include here $ds- so it could work and won't give you a error.

    if(isset($_GET['proc']) && !empty($_GET['proc'])){

                   $proc =  $_GET['proc'];
                  
                  if($proc == 'create'){

              $ds->create_ds($db_host,$db_username,$db_password);

                   $return = array('mes' => 'Created' );
              header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
              echo json_encode($return);

            }elseif($proc == 'update'){

              $ds->update_ds($db_host,$db_username,$db_password);

               $return = array('mes' => 'Updated' );
              header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
              echo json_encode($return);

            }elseif($proc == 'delete'){

              $ds->delete_ds($db_host,$db_username,$db_password);

              $return = array('mes' => 'Deleted' );
              header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
              echo json_encode($return);

            }
    }else{
             $return = array('mes' => 'The $_GET is empty , check if all parms and ajax function passing to the true file, good luck :).' );
              header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
              echo json_encode($return);
    }

?>
```

You muse include files to check.php either to use $ds- , its must basic and you should take a look how ajax works.

**EDIT:**

Here working example :
[Click on me to go to demo](http://stackoverflow.freeiz.com/) , Here you can download the example:[Click on me to download the example](http://stackoverflow.freeiz.com/ex.rar)

Working perfect,don't forget uncomment // from the check.php so it will do you'r stuff that you needed.

If you still can't make it work (even when you have WORKING DEMO) , go learn php and Javascript , this all i can help you.

**Also research google about firebug , this will help you see error's from ajax/post request, and will help you either in anyway.**

Comment: I had an error while running : " ReferenceError: dataString is not defined "

Comment: Remove line :  data: dataString,  at deleteDs and updateDs function . See edited answer,and welcome.

Comment: When I click on the buttons, it displays nothing, do we need to add any jquery-ajax libraries. Please help me

Comment: I will give you, my team viewer details. Could you please solve the problem

Comment: Okay, i'v edited i checked everything made changes and optimize the code, working perfect,look edit answer and make the changes of all php and js and html, also input should be type="submit" not button, and better give the id when you use onClick to the input itself,good luck working perfect ,and also i included to you jquery.min from google hosted library if you don't have it's needed to run jquery stuff.

Comment: Thank You for your kind help.. I will do it rightnow

Comment: I am getting the same problem, when I click on the submit buttons, it shows nothing. I have updated even by class file (only create_ds) in updated code above. Could You tell me if anything happening from the class file. Sorry to disturb you, I was struggling with this code and not able to find the problem. I can give you my teamviewer if possible

Comment: I don't know where you stuck or what you did wrong, this code working perfect , look here demo http://stackoverflow.freeiz.com/ . if you want to download the the example : http://stackoverflow.freeiz.com/ex.rar .this is all i can do,learn AJAX/JAVASCRIPT, i built you working example,if you don't know how to handle or to use php and ajax learn before. - i'v edited the answer with the latest demo and download link so you can see it clearly, good luck.

Comment: For me too.. it was showing created, updated and deleted successfully, but my class functions weren't displaying the content $ds->create_ds($db_host,$db_username,$db_password); and viceversa

Comment: It's shouldn't because you not pass it -.- . it should only do what create_ds doing have no clue.

Comment: Iam updated my sample create_ds function too. I was just doing html code and with server validation in this function, but I know when I call this functions, nothing dsiplaying

Comment: This further doesn't relative to the original question . if you have problems with you'r php code with you'r own codes open new question.

Comment: I made a new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143092/creating-php-forms-using-jquery-ajax with your suggestion

Comment: Could you please help me without using ajax and asked a question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153882/creating-php-forms-with-show-hide-functionality

Answer (score 0):

You need ajax to dynamically run some php code when binding to events such as click. Try read on .ajax()

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is executed before your DOM is created. So your jquery is not running the function again it is just showing the content that is already sent by your php functions. You need Ajax to run your php function and display data sent back by it.