# Creating PHP Forms using jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to create two reports and submit the report data to database by using two functions within a class: Here I have two submit buttons: "Create ES Report" and "Create RP Report".

(1) When I click on "Create ES Report", create_es_report form should display and be able to fill the data and submit successfully to database and if errors it should display the errors on the same div.

(2) When I click on "Create RP Report", create_rp_report form should display and be able to fill the data and submit successfully to dataabase and if errors it should display the errors on the same div.

Rightnow, When I click on any of the submit buttons, nothing was displaying

index.php

```
<html>
 <head>      
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function(){ 

      $('#es').click(function () 
      {
         create();
      });      

   });

function create(){

     $.ajax({  
      url: "check.php?proc=create",
      type: "POST",  
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(data)
      {  
             $('#returnMessage').show();
             $('#returnMessage').html(data.mes);
      }


   });  

return false;
}    

  </script>

 </head>

 <body>

<div class="container2">        
  <div style="float:left;margin:0px 0px;padding:7px;"><input type="submit" value="Create ES Report" id="es"></div>
  <div id="returnMessage" style="display:none;"></div>        
</div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

check.php

```
<?php
 require 'includes/config.inc.php';
 require 'classes/class.report.php';
 $report = new Report($db); 

 if(isset($_GET['proc']) && !empty($_GET['proc']))
 {
    $proc =  $_GET['proc'];
    if($proc == 'create')
    {
       $report->create_es_report();
       $return = array('mes' => 'Created' );
       header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
       echo json_encode($return);
    }

 }
 else
 {
     $return = array('mes' => 'The $_GET is empty , check if all parms and ajax function passing to the true file, good luck :).' );
     header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
     echo json_encode($return);
 }

?>
```

class.report.php

```
<?php
    class Report
    {
       private $db;

       public function __construct($database){
          $this->db = $database;
       }

       //CREATE DATASOURCE REPORT
       public function create_es_report()
       {
          if (isset($_POST['create_es_report']))
          {      
             $report_name = htmlentities($_POST['report_name']);            
             $from_address = htmlentities($_POST['from_address']); 
             $subject = htmlentities($_POST['subject']); 
             $reply_to = htmlentities($_POST['reply_to']); 


             if (empty($_POST['report_name']) || empty($_POST['from_address']) || empty($_POST['subject']) || empty($_POST['reply_to']))
             {
                $errors[] = '<span class="error">All fields are required.</span>';
             }
             else
             {
                if (isset($_POST['report_name']) && empty($_POST['report_name'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Report Name is required</span>'; }
                else if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['report_name']))
                {  $errors[] = '<span class="error">Report Name: Whitespace is not allowed, only alphabets and numbers are required</span>';  }

                if (isset($_POST['from_address']) && empty($_POST['from_address'])) 
                { $errors[] = '<span class="error">From address is required</span>'; }
                else if (filter_var($_POST['from_address'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
                { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Please enter a valid From address</span>';  }

                if (isset($_POST['subject']) && empty($_POST['subject'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Subject is required</span>'; }
                else if (!ctype_alnum($_POST['subject']))
                {  $errors[] = '<span class="error">Subject: Whitespace is not allowed, only alphabets and numbers are required</span>';  }

                if (isset($_POST['reply_to']) && empty($_POST['reply_to'])) { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Reply To is required</span>'; }
                else if (filter_var($_POST['reply_to'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
                { $errors[] = '<span class="error">Please enter a valid Reply-To address</span>';  }                        
             }

             if (empty($errors) === true)
             {               
                 $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO report(report_name, from_address, subject, reply_to) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");

                 $query->bindValue(1, $report_name);                
                 $query->bindValue(2, $from_address);
                 $query->bindValue(3, $subject);         
                 $query->bindValue(4, $reply_to);                 

                 try {
                   $query->execute();            
                 }

                 catch(PDOException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                 }  
                 header('Location:home.php?success');
                 exit();                 
             }
          } 

          if (isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) 
          { 
              header('Location:home.php');
              echo '<span class="error">Report is succesfully created</span>';  
          }

          ?>

          <form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
              <div style="font-weight:bold;padding:17px 80px;text-decoration:underline;">Section A</div>
              <table class="create_report">                           
                <tr><td><label>Report Name</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="report_name" required placeholder="Name of the report" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["report_name"])) echo $report_name; ?>" size="30" maxlength="30">             
                </td></tr>              

                  <tr><td><label>From</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="from_address" required placeholder="From address" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["from_address"])) echo $from_address; ?>" size="30">             
                  </td></tr>

                  <tr><td><label>Subject</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="subject" required placeholder="Subject" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["subject"])) echo $subject; ?>" size="30">             
                  </td></tr>

                  <tr><td><label>Reply To</label><span style="color:#A60000">*</span></td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="reply_to" required placeholder="Reply address" value="<?php if(isset($_POST["reply_to"])) echo $reply_to; ?>" size="30">            
                  </td></tr>

               <tr><td><input type="submit" value="create report" style="background:#8AC007;color:#080808;padding:6px;" name="create_es_report"></td></tr> 
             </table>                       
          </form>

          <?php
            //IF THERE ARE ERRORS, THEY WOULD BE DISPLAY HERE
            if (empty($errors) === false) {
               echo '<div>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</div>';
            }                  
      }   

   }//Report CLASS ENDS
```

Comment: Any messages in the console?

Comment: No Iamn't getting any errors/messages, When I run, and click the submit buttons, it displays nothing

Comment: You should try to narrow it down, this is too much to go through.

Comment: Ok.. atleast help me with one form function i.e., create_es_report, I will do for the rest

Comment: I will update it now..give me 2 mins

Comment: Why do you send url: "check.php?proc=create_es", ? it's should be      url: "check.php?proc=create", look how GET works at check.php , change all the others too.

Comment: You are sending `proc=create_es` but checking `if($proc == 'create')`? Also, you are not sending any data in your post, so `if (isset($_POST['create_es_report']))` will return false as well.

Comment: Kindly help me with only one submit button, I will do for the rest

Comment: If you keep changing the code, none of the comments and answers will make sense any more. You should put your edits below the original code.

Comment: OK... sorry for deleting the oldone.. since that was huge, I made it short

Comment: Problem, when class_report.php executes, the only connection back to the index.php page displayed in the user's browser is the jQuery AJAX call. So echo'ing the form here does not directly hit the browser. Echo'ing in class_report.php (in check.php) sends that info down the AJAX return before the json object, coming to index.php in the "success" function "data" variable in the jQuery AJAX function. Make sense?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles..I agree with your statement.. I wasn't passing any data variable here

Comment: There's a few ways to accomplish this. The one closest to what you're already doing is to add the form HTML data to an array and send that, json_encode'd back to index.php with the AJAX call for display in the div. But then we run into some roadblocks. We're missing another AJAX call to POST the form data back to the server. That call can then return the response from the database INSERT and replace the submitted form.

Comment: I expect I would echo the form in index.php and hide it. When the user clicks the "Create ES Report" button, simply reveal the hidden form. The user fills out the form and clicks the submit button. Now the AJAX call can prevent the default form submission, and instead send the form data via an AJAX POST and return the database response. Here you can replace the submitted form with the database response.

Comment: Could you please help me with a little code for replacing the submitted form with the database response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55386/discussion-between-bloodyknuckles-and-ronquiq).

Comment: If you send the back through the AJAX call, then save it to the return array before you json_encode it, let's say you give the form an array key equal to "returnForm". From there in your AJAX "success" function you can do something like `$('#returnMessage').html(data.returnForm)`;  Although I recommend you write the forms once upon initial load of index.php.

Comment: No one is giving me a correct solution.. I clearly given my code..ought stackoverflow has good developers

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that your PHP is failing and the success option is not triggering.

I would suggest adding a console write of data.res in your success option and also add an error option and add a complete option that will write something different to console so you can determine if jquery is failing or if php is failing.

As a side note, I would combine your create_es and create_rp function to 1 since they are identical except for the query string value being passed in ajax.  You would then call create_report("es") and create_report("rp") in your click events and your ajax url would be `"check.php?proc=" + report,` where report is your function param.

Answer (score -1):

You seems don't know how to handle PHP and AJAX as well.

First change the urls E.G:

```
   url: "check.php?proc=create_es",
```

to

```
   url: "check.php?proc=create",
```

Look how at check.php the GET works.

And change `type: "POST",`  to `type: "GET",`

Now to return the error's it's more complicated from just call a php function.

To return the error's you return from the create_es_report error's to the check.php file and return json format to you'r html page, this why i said LEARN ajax first.

Also don't use htmlentities i suggest you to use [HTMLPURIFER](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to santize inputs from malicious inputs.

Comment: I have edited according to your suggestion with only one submit button "Create ES Report"

Comment: Ok sure.. I will go with htmlpurifier, Thank You